# S3 - Find malformed parquet files

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I've created an Athena table to analyze a high amount of data. In the bucket to analyze are millions of files. While this worked for quite a while, I now receive the following exception:

> Row is not a valid JSON Object - JSONException: Unterminated string at
> 979 [character 980 line 1]. You may need to manually clean the data at
> location 's3://-eu-west-1/tables/'
> before retrying. Athena will not delete data in your account.

This is caused since the batch import added one or two files which seem to be malformed. I don't want to ignore these files in the analysis and therefore don't want to change the table ddl to ignore malformed json, which brings me to my question:

I there a easy way to identify malformed parquet files?

Comment: Are the files parquet or json? You can use AWS Glue DataBrew to identify which files are malformed.

Comment: How about a validation check on the file-level (e.g., Lambda function triggered by a S3 put_object event) instead of the table-level (i.e., Athena)? You can _quarantine_ the problematic files to another S3 prefix for manual inspection.

Comment: They are all json. I now added partitions, which allows me to perform a kind of binary search on the issue. I added the lambda validation now, which will help me that this will no longer happen in the future. But I'm still searching for the malformed file and will now download the full bucket and run against a python script to validate. 

@ErenSakarya can you share instructions on how this could work with Glue / databrew?